# How to extract whole line matching string from a column position using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am struggling to extract entire line matching a character from a particular column.

```
 NAME NO  TEXT                     DUR   PS R1 R2 RES HRC FAC LIM JOBNAME  FORM       A H T S E D R R C ARRIVAL  DEADLINE
 -------- ------------------------ ----- -------- --- --- ------- -------- ---------- ----------------- -------- --------
0NONR_001                          00.01  1  0  0   0             SOURINAC            Y Y N N Y N     A                  
 CPU1_002                          00.03  1  0  0   0             SOURINAX            Y Y Y N Y N     A 01 04.30         
 CPU1_003                          00.01  1  0  0   0             SOURIN23            Y Y N N Y N     N
```

I need to extract whole line where there will be matching only "Y" from column heading "T" in column No 91.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility...

Load the data into an array of strings; enumerate each row of strings; use a regular expression to parse your fixed-width data; grab the index of column 'T' in the first row; and if column T equals 'Y' for any other row, then output the whole matched row:

```
$txt = Get-Content -Path .\sample.txt
$colT = 0
foreach ($row in $txt) {
    if ($row -match '(.)(.{8}) (.{24}) (.{5}) (..) (..) (..) (...) (...) (.{7}) (.{8}) (.{10}) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.) (.{8}) (.*)') {
       if (0 -eq $colT) {
            $colT = ($matches.GetEnumerator() | % { if ('T' -eq $_.Value) { $_.Key } })
        } else {
            if ('Y' -eq $matches[$colT]) {
                $matches[0]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There may be a more efficient way (eg, using the ODBC text driver), but the code snippet above is workable, and provided as-is without warranty ;)